# I'm importing a file then trying to append, and populate, another array. I am trying to add a grade based on a mark. Typical high school example

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, integer

I get the following error and don't know how to resolve it:

```
if marks >= 70:
```

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

**MY CODE:**

```
import csv, array
filename = 'students.csv'
name = []
marks = []
grade = []
v = ""
with open(filename) as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    name.append(row[0])
    marks.append(row[1])     
    
    if marks >= 70:
        v = "A"
        grade.append(v)
    elif marks >= 60:
        v = "B"
        grade.append(v)
    elif marks >= 50:
        v = "C"
        grade.append(v)
    else:
        v = "D"
        grade.append(v)

   
print(name)
print(marks)
print(grade)
```

I have tried setting marks to:
marks = [0] * 20, along with setting the other arrays to store 20 values.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with makefiles so you should remove that tag.  Also you have not specified anywhere what _programming language_ you're using which is obviously the first thing you should say.  It looks like Python so you should say that and you should add a "python" tag to your question.

Comment: And, you should edit your question and fix the formatting: not all the code is correctly in a code block.

Comment: !:  Yes, it's Python

Comment: 1: Yes, it is Python
2: Don't know where "makefile" came from, now removed
3: I copied the code straight from my IDLE, which required "4 spaces" at the beginning of the first4 lines, or so, before it was accepted on this ite.
4: do you have any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Formatting is still incorrect, as can be seen by looking at either the preview below the editing window before you save your changes, or by looking at how your question is formatted after you save your changes.  You need a blank line between the "header" and the start of the code block.

Comment: The error shown by python is pretty clear: the variable `marks` is a list of values.  You are trying to compare a list of values to a single value.  You can't do that: single values can only be compared to other single values.  It's not clear what you want this code to do, but you can't compare `marks` (a list) to a number, as the error says.